# Computer gave up on life after restart

Tags: restart

I am using Ubuntu for a while and I don't have Internet Connection. So I got installed No updates recently. From few days its behaving strangely.I am not sure what actually cause this , either due to No updates or some messup happen inside.

When I have started my PC its starting with bunch of code flow and then this the last line where its stopping & several restarts done with negative.

```
[  16.0634321]  CR2: fffffffffffffff8
```

Help me to solve this.Thank you.

Comment: It's really difficult to understand what's going on here. The more information you can provide the better. What are the error codes? As it stands, this question is likely to get flagged as not a real question (it's too vague in my opinion). I hope you can get it solved though. I know how frustrating those situations can be. Try to be specific and add more details (error codes and such). Good luck.

Comment: There is probably an `unable to handle kernel paging request at` error just above this line. And might also be related to the video card driver. (example: https://lkml.org/lkml/2012/10/30/18 )

Comment: That looks about right, any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Try an older kernel in grub.

Answer (score 0):

During boot time, after the POST scree: Hold down the right shift button, and in the advanced menu try a different, older kernel.

Comment: Sure, that lets you boot, but that won't *fix* it. Are you going to never get a kernel update again?